# node-fetch and discord.js | how to fetch info or a title from a website every time you use a command?

Tags: discord.js, node-fetch

How to fetch info or a title from a website every time you use a command?
For example, if I use a command called `?title` I get a name of the title from a website, how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

let url = "https://www.nike.com/de/";
    fetch(url).then(res => res.text())
      .then(html => {
        const parse = cheerio.load(html)
        console.log(parse("meta[property='og:title']")[0].attribs.content)
      })
```

You need `node-fetch` and `cheerio`, so make sure you've installed it. In my example I used the Nike website, so for your website/s it could be slightly different.

So first it fetches with `node-fetch` the url and displays the result as HTML. Then we use `cheerio` to read out the HTML and get the title of the website from it.

My example returns:

```
Nike Official Site
```

Comment: It works, thanks!
But what if i want to get something from id or class?